# Alter command showing syntax error in MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, alter-table

Below is my Table schema

```
create table employee(
emp_id numeric(4),
fname varchar(10),
lname varchar(10),
mgr_id numeric(4),
hire_date date,
job_id numeric(2),
dept_id numeric(3)
);
```

Now I want to use `ALTER Table` command with `Alter Column` instead of `Modify` from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#:%7E:text=ALTER%20%5BCOLUMN%5D%20col_name%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SET%20DEFAULT%20%7Bliteral%20%7C%20(expr)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20SET%20%7BVISIBLE%20%7C%20INVISIBLE%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20DROP%20DEFAULT)
[image]

Below is my command :-

`ALTER TABLE employee ALTER COLUMN dept_id int(8);`

But I am getting a error stating syntax-error :-

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int(8)' at line 1
```

Now if I use `Modify` it works then why ALTER COLUMN is not working.The command is correct as per the even the official document.
I am using MySQL 8.0 .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are misunderstanding the manual.

From the link you mentioned the syntax alter column is used for :

```
ALTER [COLUMN] col_name {
        SET DEFAULT {literal | (expr)}
      | SET {VISIBLE | INVISIBLE}
      | DROP DEFAULT
    }
```

The following command would work properly.

```
ALTER TABLE employee ALTER COLUMN dept_id set default 111;
```

As per the data type changes you have to use MODIFY COLUMN or CHANGE COLUMN

```
ALTER TABLE employee MODIFY COLUMN dept_id  int(8);
ALTER TABLE employee CHANGE dept_id dept_id  int(8);
```

[ALTER TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#:%7E:text=ALTER%20%5BCOLUMN%5D%20col_name%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SET%20DEFAULT%20%7Bliteral%20%7C%20(expr)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20SET%20%7BVISIBLE%20%7C%20INVISIBLE%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20DROP%20DEFAULT)

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/59MO3AM7)

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing my doubt and explaining it in such an elaborate manner.